# phaser 3 stops loading after executing button code

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm having some trouble with adding 2 buttons to a phaser game. Its actually the first game from phaser 3 examples, so it works alright. However, when I try to add a button for speed up and one for speed down it stops loading after it reaches that code:

```
    buttonUp = this.add.text(550, 16, 'speed up', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });
buttonUp.setInteractive();
buttonUp.on('pointerdown', speed++);

buttonDown = this.add.text(550, 50, 'speed down', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#000' });
buttonDown.setInteractive();
buttonDown.on('pointerdown', speed--);
```

It actually stops at the

```
    buttonUp.on('pointerdown', speed++);
```

line.

any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a listener to the `pointerdown` event, i.e. a function, that will be called each time the event is dispatched. Wrap your `speed--/++` calls into a function and pass that instead.